# Service reference for WinRT DataServiceContext that supports 5.2.0.0 (Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.WindowsStore)

Tags: c#, json, windows-runtime, wcf-data-services

Is there plans on updating the [WCF Data Services Tools for Windows Store Apps](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30714) to handle v5.2 (or even better 5.3)

The JSON light format is prerequisite for my occasional connected remote workers when pushing/pulling entities.

Its not been updated since April last year.... (Or am I just missing it on the net!?)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

MSDN Answer [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataservices/thread/7c9a5338-be38-443e-a520-e98f9902b4ea) I think/hope that the data services team at MS are making the library portable.